# How do I top align two areas in an ExtJS table layout?

Tags: javascript, extjs

The ExtJS code below creates two regions to the left and right of each other, like this:

[image]

**What do I have to change to this code so that the two areas are top aligned?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var template_topbottom_top = new Ext.Panel({
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        header: false,
        items: []
    });

    var template_topbottom_bottom = new Ext.Panel({
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        header: false,
        items: []
    });    

    var template_topbottom = new Ext.Panel({
        id:'template_topbottom',
        baseCls:'x-plain',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout:'table',
        layoutConfig: {columns:2},
        defaults: {
            frame:true,
            style: 'margin: 10px 0 0 10px; vertical-align: top' //doesn't work
        },
        items:[{
                width: 210,
                height: 300,
                frame: false,
                border: true,
                header: false,
                items: [template_topbottom_top]
            },{
                width: 1210,
                height: 200,
                frame: false,
                border: true,
                header: false,
                items: [template_topbottom_bottom]
            }
        ]
    });

    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, template_topbottom, true);

</script>
```

Comment: A tip: you're over-nesting your components. Your `items` in  `template_topbottom` should reference `template_topbottom_top` and `template_topbottom_bottom` directly instead of creating a new `items` and putting them as the lonely panel in that array. Also, when your items contains a single component, there's no need to wrap it with an array.

Answer (score 11):

In ExtJS 4, you can use the tdAttrs config option:

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2,
    tdAttrs: {
        valign: 'top'
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this option best.

Answer (score 6):

For reuse, I would add a class style to your CSS file that will always top-align table layout cells.

```
<style>
    .x-table-layout-cell-top-align td.x-table-layout-cell {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

This is preferred over a previous answer that used `.table-layout td` as the CSS selector, because if you have a table within this table layout, that selector would top-align ALL cells, not just those associated with the table layout.

You would add this class to your `Ext.Panel` like so:

```
new Ext.Panel({
    cls: 'x-table-layout-cell-top-align',
    layout: 'table',
    items: [
        ...
    ]
})
```

If your panel already has a `cls` attribute, you can add additional classes with spaces:

```
    cls: 'my-container-cls x-table-layout-cell-top-align',
```

Answer (score 2):

Both suggested answers may do it. But the best answer (at least with Ext-JS 4), is to use an HBox layout and use the `align: top`, layout config.

Go to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout/hbox.html and click on the button that says: 'Align: top', or 'Align: stretch'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
            tdAttrs : {
                style : {
                    verticalAlign : 'top'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
     .x-table-layout td {
          vertical-align:top;
     }
</style>
```